# pivot and count membership of two variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a data frame in R that looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )],
                  var1 = sample(1:5,20,replace=T),
                  var2 = sample(1:5,20,replace=T))
```

Here`var1` and `var2` are categorical variables between 1 and 5.

I want to create a matrix where the column headings are `var1` 1 to 5, the row headings are `var2` 1 to 5, and the matrix is populated by the count of the numbers of entries that belong to each group.

I've tried using `reshape`, looked at the `lazyeval` package, and found questions that are similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868517/r-how-to-pivot-and-count-data-frame-ex-list-of-medical-conditions-and-the-num), but I can't get any to fit the bill.

Comment: Please add your expected output. Also, use `set.seed` for reproducibility.

Comment: Try `table(df1[-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using dcast from reshape2

```
df1 %>% reshape2::dcast(var2~var1)
reshape2::dcast(df1,var2 ~ var1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)

df1 <- data.frame(id = letters[seq( from = 1, to = 20 )],
                  var1 = sample(1:5,20,replace=T),
                  var2 = sample(1:5,20,replace=T))

df1

#    id var1 var2
# 1   a    2    5
# 2   b    2    2
# 3   c    3    4
# 4   d    5    1
# 5   e    2    2
# 6   f    5    2
# 7   g    5    1
# 8   h    4    2
# 9   i    4    5
# 10  j    1    2
# 11  k    2    3
# 12  l    1    3
# 13  m    4    3
# 14  n    2    1
# 15  o    4    5
# 16  p    3    4
# 17  q    4    4
# 18  r    5    1
# 19  s    2    4
# 20  t    4    3


df1 %>%
  count(var1,var2) %>%                     # count how many times you have each combination
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(var1 = paste0("var1_",var1)) %>%  # update variable values
  spread(var1,n, fill=0) %>%               # reshape dataset
  mutate(var2 = paste0("var2_",var2)) %>%  # update variable values
  print() -> df2

# # A tibble: 5 × 6
#     var2 var1_1 var1_2 var1_3 var1_4 var1_5
#    <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 var2_1      0      1      0      0      3
# 2 var2_2      1      2      0      1      1
# 3 var2_3      1      1      0      2      0
# 4 var2_4      0      1      2      1      0
# 5 var2_5      0      1      0      2      0
```

If you really prefer having `var2` values as row names and not as a column add this

```
df2 = data.frame(df2)
row.names(df2) = df2$var2
df2$var2 = NULL

df2

#        var1_1 var1_2 var1_3 var1_4 var1_5
# var2_1      0      1      0      0      3
# var2_2      1      2      0      1      1
# var2_3      1      1      0      2      0
# var2_4      0      1      2      1      0
# var2_5      0      1      0      2      0
```